# Difficult MS Access Query - how to combine them?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to build an access report based on data from multiple different tables within the database.

I have 3 columns which perform calculations, and I am wondering how to put this query together. All 3 columns deal with dates, but calculate them differently.

The **first column** retrieves the most recent date of action for a userid if the type of action is "B":

```
select pid, Max(date) as most_recent
from actions
where ref = 'B'
group by pid;
```

The **second column** performs a calculation based on 2 fields, one is a date and one is a number in months. I am unsure how to add these two fields so that the number is added to the date as a number of months.

what i have so far is:

```
select nummonths,Max(lastvisit) from users
```

the **third column** I need to select the first date thats **in the future** for each user (next appointment date), there will be dates before and after this date so its a little difficult:

```
select uid,date from visits
```

The code for the last 2 queries needs to be slightly modified, and I was wondering what the best approach would be to join these all together? A type of join?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for all three tables (with only the applicable fields), and a sample result? It will help answering your question.

Comment: Does the expression `Max(date)` refer to the Max() of the `actions.date` field? If so, you really need to specify that, as the Jet/ACE query optimizer may decide that you just want the Max() of the current date (since that's what the Date() function returns). In short, you really should avoid reserved words as field names, but when you have to use them (e.g., somebody else controls the table design), you can work around the problem by specifying them fully (with table name) and by surrounding the reserved word with square brackets, `Max(actions.[date])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build a report with data from the 3 queries, you will need related data to join them. In that case, please send the structure of the tables.
If you need to show 3 lists in one report, you can use subreports: create a new empty report. In design mode, you can add 3 subreports from the toolbox bar. To each of the subreport assign the record source property to the corresponding sql.

regards

Answer (score -1):

> I am unsure how to add these two fields so that the number is added to the date as a number of months.

Use the DateAdd() function:

```
SELECT DateAdd("m", 2, LastVisit) FROM ...
```

Results in a date two months from the LastVisit date.